# Android ListView Item - Right to Left Animation Menu

Tags: android, listview, animation, row, slide

In my android application I want the ListView items to move from right to left and show extra options for that row. I don't know how to ask my question so I want to show you the pictures that I took. How can I do that or what it is called ?

1. This is the first state. [image: This is the first state]
2. This is the secondstate (after click on the "PLUS" icon on the right side). [image: this is the secondstate (after click on the "PLUS" icon on the right side)]
3. This was the final state which shows the extra choices

   [image: Last screeshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE : Thanks to "ToVine", I researched for View Transitions. ViewFlipper suits for what I mentioned belove :).  This is my custom listview row's xml.

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:onClick="buttonClickHandler" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="buttonClickHandler"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView2" /> 
</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, might come in handy sometime! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that a [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html?m=1) could be used?

I'm not sure that it would work for only a small part of the screen, but it could be worth a try... :)
More info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) (d.android.com)